# Access specific port run by services using elastic ip

Tags: windows, apache, amazon-ec2, ip, elastic-ip

I have windows server 2008 R2  running in AWS (with Elastic IP)where i am running Apache service to host one of website which i can easily access using various method like

1. Like "localhost:port" works fine
2. Using server NIC ip address:port works fine.

In my current use case where i want to expose this website on my elastic IP i am not able to do so.
However if i host any website on my IIS i can access or view using my elastic IP but i am unable to host apache website on IIS.

Whenever i try to access apache one it never worked.

- I tweaked firewall setting
- I also updated conf file of apache whenever i try to give elastic IP address it will not start.

**Failed with following error message**

```
 The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> (OS 10049)The requested address is not valid in its context.  : make_sock: could not bind to address 52.xx.xx.xx:8888
```

Following is my service details of apache on services.msc

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\vcollapp\apache\bin\Apache.exe -k runservice
```

Now how can i expose my site which is running on apache service inside windows to elastic ip of AWS.

Thanks in Advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Try *binding* to 0.0.0.0? This will accept connections from all interfaces, not just localhost.

If you check your network interfaces, do you see an interface with the Elastic IP? Or do you just have your Private IP?

There are different ways of using Elastic IP's, and my assumption here is that the IP is not physically attached to your machine, but instead, you have a private IP that all traffic from the Elastic IP is routed through.

```
WAN -> Elastic -> Private
```

Comment: Thanks Matt for replying as i can see my network interfaces i can see that it is only private IP.

Comment: Is there any way that i can publish ...it... like other provider i do get n/w interface that will hold public IP but it seems to be #AWS it is not feasible ...